# Gravatar doesn't update after e-mail change

Tags: bug, gravatar

Yesterday I changed my SO e-mail address from X.Y@Z.be to X@Z.be.

~20 hours later the Gravatar still wasn't changed to the one from the new e-mail address (logged out multiple times on SO and Gravatar to try and force a cache refresh).

To work around the issue I added back my old e-mail address to Gravatar and less than 1 hour later the Gravatar was changed on SO.